# How the logic work, Assigning reverse array to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm currently learning about pointer in C Programming in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).

My understanding about pointer is, the pointer store value of the actual address in memory of a variable.

Let's say I have

```
int  var[] = {10, 100, 200};
int *ptr;
```

By assigning `var` to `ptr`

```
ptr = var;
```

`ptr` will be contained with address of the array in same sequence.

My Question,

There is an example for Decrementing a Pointer. Using Array and Pointer.
The example use

```
  ptr = &var[MAX-1];
```

Why by using above code, the pointer `ptr` could contain the reverse order of the array.

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to the last (`MAX-1`th) element of `var`. It doesn’t have an order. If you move backwards from it to the beginning of the array, you’ll be moving through the array in reverse order.

Comment: This tutorial is very clumsy, but you seem to have grasped a good understanding of pointers. The syntax `ptr = &var[MAX-1];` initializes `ptr` to point to the last element in the array.  decrementing `ptr` in a loop allows you to enumerate the array elements in *reverse* order,  but the array itself does not change.

Comment: Just to make very clear: for `ptr = var`, you do **not** set `ptr` to the address of the array, but to the address of the first element because for most useages an array name is implicitly converted (decays) to a pointer to its first element. This might sound a bit nit-picky, as both have the same **value** for most implementations. But they have different types. The address of the array is `&var` as always. Try `ptr = &var` and you will get a type-missmatch error, unless you define `int (*ptr)[];`.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, it appear i've misunderstood the concept of what `ptr = var` do at first.

Comment: @Hendrik: See many other questions here. Simply put: an array is not a pointer is not an array. It is just that the indexing (`[]`) operator has been overloaded for pointers. That - along with the [implicit conversion](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) I mentioned before - causes a lot of confusion. Please keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment:

```
ptr = var
```

store in the pointer `ptr` the address of `var,` that is the address of the array, which is the same thing as the address of the first element of the array. The reason is because the memory is organized in the following way:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+ ...
|  10 | 100 | 200 |  values of other variables, including i, ptr, etc.    
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+ ...
  ^      ^     ^
  |      |     |
 var[0] var[1] var[2]
  ^
  |
 var
```

The opertor `&variable` in C get the address of `variable`. In other word, the assignment

```
ptr = var
```

is identical to:

```
ptr = &var[0]
```

In the same way, the assignment:

```
ptr = &var[MAX-1]
```

assigns to pointer the address of the *last* element of the array (which has index `MAX-1`, that is 2).

At each iteration of the loop, the value of the variable pointed by pointer is printed, and the value of `ptr` is decremented in the second loop (note the use of `ptr--` instead of `ptr++` in the first example), so that the values of the array are printed from the last to the first.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contain the reverse order of an array. Simply it will point out
to the last position address of that array.

```
 10    20    30    //<-- values
 1100  1104  1108  //<-- let's take pointer address.
```

After this line,

```
ptr = &var[MAX-1];

ptr will points to 1108. //memory address
```

So if you decrement the pointer value then it will decrement the address position and get the value in reverse order. So it will print the output as

```
30 20 10
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Arrays in C are just contiguous areas of memory. They don't have strides or any other sort of metadata associated with them (though they may have a size if they are given one on declaration). You can't create an array that increments "backwards" through memory.